# Wordpress 3.2.1 Featured Image Size and Crop

Tags: image, wordpress, wordpress-featured-image

I need help finding where and how to change the size and crop of a featured image within a post. I've looked in functions.php and init.php, but with no success. I'm using a child theme of the inLine theme.

The current height is set for 130px.

I've tried changing the css, but that only stretches the image.

Comment: What is exactly what you want, change the default sizes for thumbnail and medium images, or changes the way that images get resizes?

Comment: I want to change the featured Image height, so I can display more of the image.

Comment: If you want to have no problem with height I recommend you to set your height options to 0 ( Settings > Multimedia ), or you can set your own images sizes in functions.php, something like add_image_size( 'thumb-1', 320, 130, true );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your functions.php, paste one of these and adjust pixel width and height to your liking:

```
set_post_thumbnail_size( 100, 100 ); // 100 pixels wide by 100 pixels tall, box resize mode
```

OR:

```
set_post_thumbnail_size( 100, 100, true ); // 100 pixels wide by 100 pixels tall, hard crop mode
```

Comment: set_post_thumbnail didn't do anything. Didn't they change post_thumbnail to something different in the newer versions of wp?

Answer (score 3):

Do this in functions.php:

```
add_image_size( 'name-of-your-image-size', 600, 300, true );
```

Or if you'd rather use a plugin-

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/additional-image-sizes-zui/

And then in your post, retrieve it like so in your single.php or loop:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('name-of-your-image-size'); ?>
```